# Canonical form for romanizations of Arabic town names in Syria mapping to latitude/longitude

Tags: places, arabic

Is there a Python package or database source which would allow me to go from various romanizations of Arabic town names in Syria and Iraq to latitude/longitude pair?

Here is an example where the left romanization is one kind used by a US Government record collection and the other appears in a [Syrian government press release](https://sana.sy/en/?p=124296).  The Government names seem to be more well known and look-upable than the names used by the Syrian Government.  I would like to find a canonical reduction of the two into a single reliable name:

- Al Bāqāt::al-Bakat
- Al Ismā‘ilīyah::al-Ismailiya
- Arjul::Arjal
- Batrānah::Batrana
- Bīshah::Bisha
- Buraydah::Barda
- Burj ‘Izzāwī::Burj Ghazawi
- Burj Subaynah::Burj Sabna
- Buslah::Bassila
- Buwayḑah al Kabīrah::Bouaida Kabira
- Buwayḑah aş Şaghīrah::Bouaida saghira
- Ghurayrīfah::Gharirfa
- Jabal al Mudawwar::Jabal al-Madwar
- Jafr Manşūr::Ja’far Mansour
- Jubb al Khāfī::Jub al-Khafi
- Jubb at Tīnah::Jub al-Tina
- Judaydah::Jadida
- Kafr Ḩawt::Kafro Hoot
- Khanāşir::Khanaser
- Khirbat al Ma‘ājīr::Khirbet al-Muaijer
- Madāyin Kabīrah::Madaen Kabir
- Munbaţiḩ::Munbateh
- Rasm al Bās::Rasm al-Bassas
- Rasm al Karkūr::Rasm al-Karkour
- Rasm Shawkān::Rasm Shoukan
- Rujaylah::Rjaila
- Şuwayyān::Soyan

Comment: You may have more luck on the Open Data Stack Exchange. I would suggest asking there too.

https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Will do.  I hope nobody spanks me for cross-posting.  I've pretty much verified that the names on the right are ad hoc romanizations written casually by Syrian government press release writers.  So there is nothing out there that will take those idiosyncratic romanizations back to "official" geonames.org type romanizations.